# Exception: No property delete found for type void in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Jpa and facing an exception when I deployed the project
I have used findAll() method in service and serviceImpl class and I received an exception, this is my source:

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITY")
public class City {

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  // get, set method      
}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface CityJpaRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<City, Integer> { 
}
```

Service class:

```
public interface CityService {
   public List<City> findAll();
}
```

ServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
public class CityServiceImpl implements CityService {

@Resource
private CityJpaRepositoryCustom cityRepository; 

@Override
@Transactional
public List<City> findAll() {       
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    return cityRepository.findAll();        
}
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class CityController {

@Autowired
private CityService cityService;    

@RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getListCity(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                          HttpServletResponse response,
                                          ModelMap model) {     
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("manageCity");

    List<City> cityList = cityService.findAll();
    mav.addObject("cityList", cityList);

    return mav;
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SOLR -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-solr.verion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WEB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Log message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityJpaRepositoryCustom': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
```

I have found some same topic but it's not get good result for me, How to fix this exception? thank you so much!

Comment: I don't get any error with the provided code. Have you defined a custom `delete` method in `CityJpaRepositoryCustom`?

Comment: Hi @manish: I don't define delete method, just exist one fillAll(), I don't know why, maybe this is cause by configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your version of Spring Boot to the latest (1.5.1.RELEASE).

You're using an ancient version which will in turn be pulling in an old version of Spring Data which may have not supported delete.

Comment: to update latest version I have to spending a lot the time to re-code, however it worked, thanks Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use delete operation but don't want to update [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), you have to write your own delete implementation. Example:

```
public interface CityJpaRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<City, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from City where name = :name")
    void deleteByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Related docs:

1. [Using `@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) annotation
2. [`@Modifying`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html) annotation
3. [`@Param`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/Param.html) annotation